# Does not understand how Javascript work in this code (using Coffeescript, Commander in Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, node-commander

I have some trouble using Commander in Node.js: parseInt not working properly in my code:

```
commander = require 'commander'

#parseInt = (str) => parseInt str   #I tried to include this line but not work.

commander
  .option '-n, --connection [n]', 'number of connection', parseInt, 5000
  .option '-m, --message [n]', 'number of messages', parseInt, 5000
  .parse process.argv

console.log commander.connection 
console.log commander.message
```

When I use option -n 10000 -m 10000, the console produce:

```
NaN
NaN
```

I also notice this code with class work:

```
commander = require 'commander'

class MyCommand
  parseOpt: =>
    commander
      .option '-n, --connection [n]', 'number of connection', @parseInt, 5000
      .option '-m, --message [n]', 'number of messages', @parseInt, 5000
      .parse process.argv
    (@connection, @message} = commander
  run: =>
    @parseOpt()
    console.log @connection 
    console.log @message        
  parseInt: (str) => parseInt str

new MyCommand().run()
```

Why my code does not work while the 'class' code work? How to make my code work without using class? Thanks~

Comment: Looking at the code provided, I think it should work if you replaced `@parseInt` with `parseInt`. Can you describe how it is not working - what is the exact error. Could you include the code as you changed it too?

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech Thanks for replying. Pls check my edited my question (I changed it before after not getting any reply for a while).

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech I have managed to make my code work after using myParseInt instead of parseInt: 
    myParseInt = (string, defaultValue) ->
      int = parseInt(string, 10)
      if typeof int == 'number'
        int
      else
        defaultValue
But i still dont understand why using those code work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseInt` expects 2 arguments: string to parse, and base number (defaults to `10`).

`commander` calls provided function with 2 arguments: string to parse, and it's default value.
So in the end your `parseInt` tries to parse string `'10000'` in base 5000, which is invalid base.

Try this:

```
commander = require 'commander'

commander
  .option '-n, --connection [n]', 'number of connection', Number, 5000
  .option '-m, --message [n]', 'number of messages', Number, 5000
  .parse process.argv

console.log commander.connection
console.log commander.message
```

Also, the reason why your `parseInt = (str) => parseInt str` does not work, is that you're defining recursive function that just calls itself.

Comment: Thanks. I think your answer is mostly correct. However, there's one point that I dont understand: `parseInt = (str) => parseInt str` work with the 'class' clode?

Comment: it works in class, because `this.parseInt` and `parseInt` are 2 different functions: `this.parseInt` is method of class instance, while `parseInt` is just global func. While `parseInt = (str)-> parseInt str` is just redifining global function and calling itself. To fix that, just rename it, like `parseInteger = (str)->parseInt str`